# change dtype of tensor (from existing model) from uint8 to float

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

hi i want to change the input dtype of an exiqting model from uint8 to float , i loaded model but i don't know how to modify the input dtype , please help me

```
def load( checkpoint_filename, input_name="images",
             output_name="features"):
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(checkpoint_filename, "rb") as file_handle:
        graph_def =  tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(file_handle.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="net")
    input_var = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
        "net/%s:0" % input_name)
    print(input_var.dtype.as_numpy_dtype)
load('./converttf2tflite/mars-small128TOtrt.pb')
```